# React Portal inserting content multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-portal

Created a React portal and it works well except that it renders the requested content into the portal twice.

[image]

It also seems to run the function that inserts the content many times:

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

export default function Portal({
  id
}) {
  console.log("Inserting into portal");
  return (
    <>
      {ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <div>MY REACT CONTENT</div>,
        window.document.getElementById(`portal-${id}`)
      )}
    </>
  );
}

ProductPrice.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

How can I structure this file to ensure that the portal is only created once?

Comment: Can you share the code of the component where you invoke this Portal component?

Comment: I believe when you create a React Portal it inserts the element in the DOM, but doesn't remove it when the component is rerendered, so I guess at every update a new div is inserted

Answer (score 0):

I believe the component where you are using Portal is being re-rendered resulting Portal being re-rendered. You can wrap your Portal with `React.memo()` and that might solve it,